# Haskell sort values from list

Tags: list, sorting, haskell, indexing

I'm new to haskell and I want to sort list of strings. For example I have a list that is in my variable `ff` that contain three strings `["1 8 8 5 6", "1 4 2 3", "5 4 9 7 9 9"]` and I want to sort them so my result should look like  `["1 5 6 8 8", "1 2 3 4", "4 5 7 9 9 9"]` Here's my code that perfectly works

```
import System.IO  
import Control.Monad
import Data.List
import Data.Function
import Data.Array
import Data.Char

sortNumeric = sortBy (compare `on` (read :: String -> Int))
wordsWhen :: (Char -> Bool) -> String -> [String]
wordsWhen p s =  case dropWhile p s of
                      "" -> []
                      s' -> w : wordsWhen p s''
                            where (w, s'') = break p s'
main = do
  file <- readFile "test.txt"
  let ff = map ((!!) (lines file)) [1,3..(length (lines file) - 1)]
  let splitString =  wordsWhen (==' ') (ff!!0)
  let sortedResult = sortNumeric (splitString)
  print sortedResult
```

Problem is with this line `let splitString =  wordsWhen (==' ') (ff!!0)` I always get first element of the list, so only first element is sorted. How can I pass all values of a list? Here's what I tryied to do `let splitString =  wordsWhen (==' ') (ff!![0..(length(ff)-1)])` unfortunately this doesn't work. Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it easily with `map` and a niftry trick to use `words`, `sort` and then `unwords` (to restore the whitespace).

```
Prelude> let ff=["1 8 8 5 6", "1 4 2 3", "5 4 9 7 9 9"]
Prelude> import Data.List
Prelude Data.List> map (unwords . sort . words) ff
["1 5 6 8 8","1 2 3 4","4 5 7 9 9 9"]
```

Edit: Improvement to correctly sort numeric values:

```
import Data.List
let ff=["11 8 8 5 6", "11 4 2 3", "5 4 9 7 99 9"]
let sortNumeric = (map show) . sort . (map (read :: String -> Int))
map (unwords . sortNumeric . words) ff
```

result:

```
["5 6 8 8 11","2 3 4 11","4 5 7 9 9 99"]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but what is `Prelude` after implementing it in my code I get Not in scope: data constructor `Prelute`

Comment: `Prelude>` is just the prompt from the interactive interpreter, not part of the code.

Comment: Hi Dave, sorry if the `Prelude>` part was confusing, I just wrote it quickly in `ghci` and copy pasted from the terminal.

Comment: Note that this is String sorting and may not be accurate for numbers.  For example  `sort ["1","2","11"]` will give `["1","11","2"]`